# Nvidia tegra profiler 1.0 crashes

Tags: android, android-ndk, profiling, nvidia

Nvidia tegra profiler 1.0 gets crash when used for profiling my application (NDK build) on any android device.

any advice will be helpful. or please suggest any other profiler.

Comment: As this is recently-released software, you might want to include the exact build number and other details about your crash, such as your sampling settings.

Answer (score 0):

It would be really helpful (to give you an answer) if you provide some information about your test system like:

1. Device(s) you tried to use and android version(s)
2. Tegra Profiler version
3. Attach logs from profiler components
4. Screenshot with error message

Have you read Tegra Profiler User Guide? It has troubleshooting section...